# When I try to upload a file in ASP.NET MVC, it shows as null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

For some reason the paramater `OriginalLocation` is always `null` in the following code. What am I doing wrong?

#### Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult File(HttpPostedFileBase OriginalLocation, FileModel model)
 {
     byte[] binaryData = null;
     if (OriginalLocation != null && OriginalLocation.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         binaryData = new byte[OriginalLocation.ContentLength];
         OriginalLocation.InputStream.Read(binaryData, 0,
                          OriginalLocation.ContentLength);
         if (model.UploadFile(OriginalLocation))
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Account");
         }
     }
 return View();
 }
```

#### View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MasterPage.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NISE.Web.TestForum.Models.File.FileModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
Find upload
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

<% using (Html.BeginForm("File", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   { %> 
<%--<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/File/File">--%>

      <input type="file" name="OriginalLocation" id="OriginalLocation"  />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

<%--</form>--%>
<%} %>

</asp:Content>
```

#### Model:

```
public bool UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase OriginalLocation)
    {
        if (OriginalLocation != null)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(OriginalLocation.FileName);
            OriginalLocation.SaveAs(@"C:\" + filename);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the FileModel model parameter from your Action method.  Nothing is being passed to it, and so it's screwing up model binding (unless there is more code in the view that you have deleted from your post).